# how do i calculate correlation between corresponding columns of two matrices and not getting other correlations as output

Tags: r, correlation

I have these data

```
> a
     a    b    c
1    1   -1    4
2    2   -2    6
3    3   -3    9
4    4   -4   12
5    5   -5    6

> b
     d    e    f
1    6   -5    7
2    7   -4    4
3    8   -3    3
4    9   -2    3
5   10   -1    9

> cor(a,b)
           d            e             f
a  1.0000000    1.0000000     0.1767767
b -1.0000000    -1.000000    -0.1767767
c  0.5050763    0.5050763    -0.6964286
```

The result I want is just:

```
cor(a,d) = 1
cor(b,e) = -1
cor(c,f) = -0.6964286
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably personally just use `diag`:

```
> diag(cor(a,b))
[1]  1.0000000 -1.0000000 -0.6964286
```

But you could also use `mapply`:

```
> mapply(cor,a,b)
         a          b          c 
 1.0000000 -1.0000000 -0.6964286
```

Answer (score 12):

The first answer above calculates all pairwise correlations, which is fine unless the matrices are large, and the second one doesn't work.  As far as I can tell, efficient computation must be done directly, such as this code borrowed from borrowed from the arrayMagic Bioconductor package, works efficiently for large matrices:

```
> colCors = function(x, y) { 
+   sqr = function(x) x*x
+   if(!is.matrix(x)||!is.matrix(y)||any(dim(x)!=dim(y)))
+     stop("Please supply two matrices of equal size.")
+   x   = sweep(x, 2, colMeans(x))
+   y   = sweep(y, 2, colMeans(y))
+   cor = colSums(x*y) /  sqrt(colSums(sqr(x))*colSums(sqr(y)))
+   return(cor)
+ }

> set.seed(1)
> a=matrix(rnorm(15),nrow=5)
> b=matrix(rnorm(15),nrow=5)
> diag(cor(a,b))
[1]  0.2491625 -0.5313192  0.5594564
> mapply(cor,a,b)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> colCors(a,b)
[1]  0.2491625 -0.5313192  0.5594564
```

Comment: Is it possible to add p-values and also adjusted p-values for multiple comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

`mapply` works with data frames but not matrices. That is because in data frames each column is an element, while in matrices each entry is an element.

In the answer above `mapply(cor,as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b))` works just fine.

```
set.seed(1)
a=matrix(rnorm(15),nrow=5)
b=matrix(rnorm(15),nrow=5)
diag(cor(a,b))
[1]  0.2491625 -0.5313192  0.5594564
mapply(cor,as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b))
    V1         V2         V3 
 0.2491625 -0.5313192  0.5594564
```

This is much more efficient for large matrices.

Answer (score 1):

For larger matrices `Rfast::corpairs` is a bit faster than `mapply`.

```
library(Rfast)

a <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1e3)
b <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1e3)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  diag = diag(cor(a, b)),
  mapply = as.numeric(mapply(cor,as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b))),
  corpairs = corpairs(a, b),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#>      diag 1294.1268 1303.72885 1313.41297 1306.84705 1314.44330 1426.1978   100
#>    mapply   49.4884   54.91380   58.52463   57.11995   60.49635  115.6425   100
#>  corpairs    8.6714   12.57265   15.29742   14.81435   16.18880   65.3170   100
```